# Node API response issue

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have deployed node api in IIS & https is binded to 443 port.

In the code, I'm using process.env.PORT || 446.

When I browse, I couldn't get the response from https://localhost:443 instead I'm getting it from https://localhost:446

server.js

```
var https = require('https');
var fs    = require('fs');

var options = {
    pfx : fs.readFileSync('./secure.pfx'),
    passphrase : 'secure'
}

var app = require('./app')

var port = process.env.PORT || 446

var server = https.createServer(options,app)

server.listen(port)
```

webconfig.js

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

   <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="sendToNode">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It doesn't run on the bound port but always take 446.

Comment: Start your node process  with this command "PORT=443 node server.js" .

Comment: Or like this considering that you are on a windows machine "node server.js -port 443".

Comment: @khan, Not running through localhost but running in iis.